# Executing Sample of Amazon Fire-Phone SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, amazon-fire-os

I am trying to run the sample of Fire-Phone SDK in Eclipse and Android Studio but in the XML file it gives the Error. Error is "No Resource Identifier found for 'headerTitle','actionMenu','headerSubtitle', etc. in amazon " and also 
i will follow the all step which is described in the given link https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-phone/docs/implementing-headernavigationbar 
in amazon developer site.....

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Eclipse for accessing amazon xml resources.

This what they say in their website

> "Note: Applications that need to compile with Amazon XML resources are
>   not supported in Eclipse, and require use of the Gradle plugin."

Move to Android Studio :)

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-phone/docs/setup

Comment: Please provide the link of website where they can say require use of the Gradle plugin....

Comment: Edited answer to add link